# UX Design Reference

Tags: user-experience

Hi Ive been planning on doing a social network project and im wondering if there are readings on UX Design that I can read to base my site design on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868297/good-books-resources-for-user-interface-design) question. My personal favorite is [Steve Krug's Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758).

Comment: stupid me. sorry havent checked other similar question. thanks for the link though

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in reading specifically about how other social networking sites are reviewed.

Like when Facebook Redesigned:
http://www.techcrunch.com/2006/09/05/new-facebook-redesign-more-than-just-aesthetics/

Or a Twitter lead designer profile:
http://www.fastcompany.com/blog/cliff-kuang/design-innovation/design-mind-behind-twitter-hes-21

How Ning works:
http://www.technologyreview.com/communications/18321/

Definitely use as many social networking sites as possible to get inspired.

Comment: Additionally, SmashingMagazine just wrote this today...seems topical for you. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/17/designing-social-interfaces-overview-and-practical-techniques/

Answer (score -1):

I have found ***Seductive Interaction Design*** helpful. There is a section about profile completeness and how to incorporate positive goals that compels your user to take the steps necessary towards completeness.

[http://www.amazon.com/Seductive-Interaction-Design-Effective-Experiences/dp/0321725522](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321725522)

Other helpful sections on how to build in fun distractions and more importantly coming on too strong (and how not to!).

Hope this helps!